# How to show the data on the page only if particular function calls in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

In angular application I have prepared the map using angular and created the circle with latitude and longitude coming from the server.And I have created the moving marker on the circle it should turn to red if it is inside the circle and turn to blue outside the circle.I have written the conditions.

But now I have to write the conditions like if the marker(i.e drone image)comes inside it should show the details(droneid)on the page.otherwise remove the data(i.e id).

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
var latlngs = this.drones.Drone.latlong;
var droneid = this.drones.Drone.Droneid;
var START_IDX = 2;
var latlngIdx = START_IDX; // 0 = Circle, 1 = First position
var marker;
var circlemark;
latlngs.forEach((latlong, idx)=>{
    var latlng = L.latLng(latlong.lat,latlong.lon)
        if(idx === 0){
      var jammer = {"name":"Jammer 1","lat":latlong.lat,"lon":latlong.lon,"isCollapsed":false};
      var sensor = {"name":"Sensor 1","lat":latlong.lat,"lon":latlong.lon};
      circlemark = L.circle(latlng,{radius:5000}).addTo(map);
      localStorage.setItem('jammerdet',JSON.stringify(jammer));
      localStorage.setItem('sensordet',JSON.stringify(sensor));
      
      marker = L.marker(latlng,{icon:sensoricon}).addTo(map);
         }else if(idx===1){
      marker = L.marker(latlng,{icon:myIcon})
      .bindTooltip( this.drones.Drone.Droneid  ).addTo(map)
    }else if(idx>=2){
      var circleMarker = L.circle(latlng,{color: 'red'},{radius:100}).addTo(map)
    }
});
function nextLatLng(){
    if(marker){
        if(latlngIdx === latlngs.length){ // Beginn on idx 2 if last idx is reached
            latlngIdx = START_IDX;
                    }
        marker.setLatLng(latlngs[latlngIdx]);
        if(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(latlngs[0].lat,latlngs[0].lon,latlngs[latlngIdx].lat,latlngs[latlngIdx].lon) <= 5.0){
          
          circlemark.setStyle({color:'red'});
          }else{
          circlemark.setStyle({color:'blue'});
        }
        latlngIdx++;
        setTimeout(nextLatLng,TIME); // recall nextLatLng() after 1000 ms
    }
}
nextLatLng();
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
dronedetails(){
  this.drones=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("drones"));
  console.log("drones",this.drones)
  console.log("array",this.drones.Drone.latlong);
  console.log("droneID",this.drones.Drone.Droneid);
    }
```

**Dashboard.component.html**

```
    <h4 style="color:black;" id="drr">Drones</h4>
<ul id="DroneId">
      <li style="color: black;">{{this.drones.Drone.Droneid}}</li>
    </ul>
<h4 style="color:black;" >Jammers</h4>
    
    <ul *ngIf="jammer" style="color:black;">
      <li>{{jammer.name}} <button  style="font-size: 11px;border-radius: 8px;font-weight: bold;background-color: green;" 
        (click)=" jammer.isCollapsed =!jammer.isCollapsed ; jammer.isCollapsed? STOP(jammer.name): START(jammer.name)  "> 
        {{ jammer.isCollapsed ?   'STOP' : 'START'  }}</button></li>
      <li>{{jammer.lat}}</li>
      <li>{{jammer.lon}}</li>
    </ul>
<h4 style="color:black;">Sensors</h4>
    <ul *ngIf="sensordet">
      <li>{{sensordet.name}}</li>
      <li>{{sensordet.lat}}</li>
      <li>{{sensordet.lon}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Now I Have to show the drones,sensors and jammers data on **dashboard.component.html** only if the drone comes inside the circle which is in red color(written the condition above)otherwise It should not show the all the data(drones,sensors,jammers) on the page.

*Can anyone help me regarding this.*

Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: You will have a better chance of an answer if you simplify your question.

Comment: So you already set the circle to red or blue. Just create a boolean variable to show/hide the data. In your "function nextLatLng(){" statement, where the If is for red/blue, just set the boolean to true/false when you want to show/hide the data and then in the html, do a *ngIf='' based on the boolean to show/hide the data

Comment: Thanks,But I am unable to get the response can you  please provide the code for the above.